# Pandas: Convert String column to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe  with string column which contains timestamp as "20000530 172700"
How to change elegantly such string  to "2000-05-30 17:27:00" ?
Dataframe contains > 10k rows. I don't want take each value,insert "-" and ":" to specified positions. Is there a solution using mask?

Comment: Take a look at ```.datetime()```.  The format your strings are currently in might make it more difficult though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df["my_column"])
```

If you want to customize it, you can use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), e.g.:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["my_column"]).dt.strftime('%d%b%Y')
#The format will be something like 30May2000
```

You can check all the datetime format codes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: Thanks, Pablo! Just pd.to_datetime(df["my_column"]) gave me wished result. Thanks again!